# Superscript + Hyperlink in CommonMark markdown

Tags: markdown, commonmark

To superscript in CommonMark Markdown, one would use (according to Dillinger.io):

```
TESTWORD^GOOGLE^
```

To create a link, I would implement:

```
[GOOGLE](https://www.google.com)
```

But combining the two does not work:

```
TEST^[GOOGLE](https://www.google.com)^
```

In Dillinger.io / CommonMark, this simply yields a superscript with the text

```
[GOOGLE](https://www.google.com).
```

How can I combine the superscript and the link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The CommonMark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/) does not currently support superscript (as of v0.29).

However, it looks like Dillginger.io does support superscript inside of link labels using formatting like this:

```
TEST[^GOOGLE^](https://www.google.com)
```